# ColorBox Scroll Bar Issue: Hidden UNDER "X" (Close out Button)

Tags: javascript, html, css, colorbox

Live Example:
http://www.careersinmusic.com/aaaa-testing-link.aspx

First off, the Scroll bar is going UNDER the Close out Button. Its still functional, but an eye sore.

SECOND:
I have the module set to be 600px tall, and thats working great. The content (a 986px tall GIF) does not want to scroll all the way. The scroll bar is only giving me an extra 20px of the image. Not sure what the issue is here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would prefer not to make separate HTML pages for this ( i have 3 more to do )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of #book-previews to 600px, same as the parent div (#cboxLoadedContent),

From:

```
#book-previews {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  height: 986px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 775px;
}
```

To:

```
#book-previews {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 775px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

After the above, the horizontal scroll-bar of doom is rendered for the #book-previews image, set the following to mitigate that,

```
#book-previews {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 775px;
}
```